# Is there a way with Google App Script to highlight text in a document when it is modified?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to highlight text in colour when it's modified in a Google document. It should simply be coloured if someone changes the text. Is such a thing possible and how do you implement it as a layman?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far. Did you take a look at https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/ ?

Comment: suggestions mode?

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately the trigger [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) only works for Google Spreadsheets

If you want to want to retrieve modifications made in a Google Docs document, there is a rather convoluted workaround I can think of.

1. Retrieve your [revision history](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) with [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) - can be accessed within Apps Script with [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
2. Retrieve the revision's [exportLinks](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions#resource) and [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) them as `text\html` . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987270/11599789) for more information
3. Retrieve the revision test as [contents of the exportLinks Url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415475/11599789)
4. Pass the revision text to a [function to highlight text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16924466/11599789)

Maybe just seeing the revision history (where latest changes will be highlighted) will be sufficient for your purposes.